# If hash is nil, how to set the key?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm storing a book object in a Hash using its title as the key. If the book's already in the hash, I'm calling another method, so I do a check to see if it's in the hash using the key? method. However, I'm getting an error:

> undefined method `key?` for `nil::NilClass`

```rb
     if self.bookshelf.key?(title)
```

Why is `self.bookshelf` nil? Note, in the way I'm using it in my code, I haven't added anything to it yet, at this point, so the check if the key is present at this point in the runtime is moot, however, I will need to check later. So when I comment out that bit of code and do

```rb
self.bookshelf[title] = book
```

I get:

> undefined method `[]` for `nil:NilClass`

Why is the bookshelf nil if I create a new Hash in the `new` method of the class?

```
class Shelf
  attr_accessor :bookshelf
  def new
    bookshelf = Hash.new()
  end 
  def add_book(title, book)
    if self.bookshelf.key?(title)
      #do something 
    else
      self.bookshelf[title] = book
    end 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bookshelf =` (without `self`) sets only a local variable that is not set in the scope of another method. Instead, you need to use `@bookshelf` or (when working with `attr_accessor`) `self.bookshelf =`. Note that the `self.` is not require when reading the value via the getter method created by `attr_accessor`.

Furthermore, you do not implement a `new` method in Ruby to create a new instance. Instead, you implement `initialize` that is one of the methods being called when calling `new`.

This should work for you:

```
class Shelf
  attr_accessor :bookshelf

  def initialize
    self.bookshelf = {} # `{}` is idiomatic Ruby for `Hash.new`
  end 

  def add_book(title, book)
    if bookshelf.key?(title)
      puts "Title '#{title}' is already in the bookshelf"
    else
      bookshelf[title] = book
    end 
  end 
end 

shelf = Shelf.new
shelf.add_book('Book 1', '...')
shelf.add_book('Book 2', '...')

shelf.add_book('Book 1', '...')
#=> Title 'Book 1' is already in the bookshelf
```

Comment: And if you would implement `new`, you would implement it as a class method.

Comment: @Stefan And I'd like to emphasize for the newer users to Ruby **never implement `new`** (until you know enough Ruby to understand why you never implement `new`). If you want an alternate constructor use a different name.